# Make collection route generic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with Rails 3.2 in a project, and I need to create a route for all controllers.

For now, the route is:

```
resources :people do
  collection do
    get 'search_for'
  end
end
```

I need thsi "search_for" action for all controllers in application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this route

```
match "/:controller/search_for" => redirect("/%{controller}/search_for")
```

UPDATE:  the route above will not work and will cause a redirect loop error simply because it causes a 301 redirect to the same route. solution is to just use

```
match "/:controller/search_for"
```

be sure to place this route above all routes so routes that go to the show action will not override this route like.

Comment: I got this error: "GET http://localhost:3000/pacientes/procura.json…" 404 (Not Found) "

Comment: error in rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person with id=search_for):

Answer (score 1):

Simply put this above all routes as:

```
get ':controller/search_for'
```